# Linux Mint 17: How do I switch key bindings from the command line?

Tags: linux-mint, console, key-binding

I changed the key binding `switch-to-workspace-1` via Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Workspace Management.

Is it also possible to this via the console? Vecause when I use the command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1`<br/>`@as []
```

I had expected something like `@as [Alt+1]`. How do I use the console to change the key bindings?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The syntax is

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Alt>1']"
```

I have this from my scratchpad, but I'll look for online reference and edit it in later.

EDIT: The Ubuntu Wiki says something similiar: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings

Comment: I tried it for <alt>8 but it is not working